# Why are some OSGi bundles in Eclipse extracted into directoris instead of being packaged as JARs?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

I am trying to piece together some bundles for our internal testing. We are using Eclipse Equinox as OSGi implementation. I have hit a missing bundle (`org.eclipse.jdt.debug`). I was looking for it and found out it is not JAR but it is extracted into a directory instead.

Why is that? Is there any technical reason for some bundles in Eclipse being extracted and others being present as JARs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some plug-ins contain resources that need to be accessed by other code or by using normal Java file based APIs, so cannot be packed into a jar.

The MANIFEST.MF of a plug-in can specify:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

to specify that the plugin be installed as a directory. If the plug-in is part of a feature this can also be specified in the `unpack` attribute in the `feature.xml` entry for the plug-in.

I think the `jdimodel.jar` in the `org.eclipse.jdt.debug` needs to be accessed directly by a Java JVM so the plug-in is a directory.

Comment: Following [the commit](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug.git/commit/org.eclipse.jdt.debug/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF?id=6d1792f68997fa49b1983e3301d599c5e2db3756) and the [corresponding bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379726) the reason is given in [comment #2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379726#c2) that it is or was required to run the test in the build (I do not know if it is still required these days).